# Same action for button and an nav item

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer

I'm having 3 item and 3 buttons. For the buttons I have created a call to action functions and that intent is working fine. I would like add the same action to my nav items. How can I do that?

To be very clear. I need to show same activity when I click the button and the nav item. I'm new to Android. So I don't know even this is possible or not. Or I'm using the proper way to do this.

These are the intents I'm using for the buttons:

```
public void exploreActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExploreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void packagesActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PackagesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void dealsActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DealsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

These are my menu items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@id/explore"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_exp"
        android:title="@string/Explore" />
    <item
        android:id="@id/menuPack"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_pack"
        android:title="@string/packages" />
    <item android:id="@id/dealsMenu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_deals"
        android:title="@string/deals" />
    </menu>
```

These are the three buttons I'm having now

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/explore"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/explorebutton"
                android:onClick="exploreActivity"
                android:text="@string/Explore"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#838383"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homelogo" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/packages"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/packagebutton"
                android:onClick="packagesActivity"
                android:text="@string/packages"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#838383"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/deals"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/explore"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homelogo" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/deals"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/dealsbutton"
                android:onClick="dealsActivity"
                android:text="@string/deals"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#838383"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/homelogo" />
```

I have made the changes on my HomeActivity.Java

```
package com.example.windows81.travelspoc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    ViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private int dotscount;
    private ImageView[] dots;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mtoggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mtoggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mtoggle);
        mtoggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 2000, 4000);

        dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){
            dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.incative_dot));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(8, 0, 8,0);

            sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);
        }
        dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_active));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.incative_dot));
                }
                dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_active));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(mtoggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {

            HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    }else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    }else{
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }


                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void myMethod(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExploreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void exploreActivity(View view){
        myMethod();
    }

    public void packagesActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,PackagesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void dealsActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DealsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.explore) {
            Log.d("Explore","Clicked");
            myMethod();
        }
        return false;
    }
   }
```

But I got the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.windows81.travelspoc, PID: 3485
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.windows81.travelspoc/com.example.windows81.travelspoc.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2625)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2691)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:188)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1526)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5790)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.windows81.travelspoc.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:40)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6275)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2691) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:188) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1526) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5790) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Create method like this

```
public void myMethod(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExploreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

than call your method in **`Button like this`**

```
public void exploreActivity(View view){
        myMethod()
    }
```

now Implement **`NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`** the listener in your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
              NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListene
```

than set

```
     NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.account_navigation_view);
   `mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`
```

Override the method

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.explore) {
            Log.d("Explore","Clicked");
             myMethod()
        }
}
```

Comment: These are the things I have done
    public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
NavigationView mNavigationView;
and on create
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 public void myMethod(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExploreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void exploreActivity(View view){
        myMethod();
    }

Comment: @ShyjuKrishnankutty didn't get you

Comment: public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.explore) {
            Log.d("Explore","Clicked");
            myMethod();
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: @ShyjuKrishnankutty you shold edit in your question what issue your are facing currentle

Comment: @ShyjuKrishnankutty happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

For navigation menu -> Create it using NavigationView

here is proper example link for it -> http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2016/02/navigationview-example-in-android.html

Using this method you can create Nav Menu from Menu option.

Another method is using Recyclerview -> make Recyclerview and Handle all your intent through adapter.(If you have dynamic list or Long list then i would suggest 2nd method.)